# Find two matching pattern from same file python

Tags: python

I have a file with 1000 lines where I need to find a matching pattern, once I found and need to find out next matching the pattern from there, not from the beginning

example:

```
match1= Unlock event detected
match2= presence service not connected

.....
.....
10:12:53,presence service not connected
.....
.....
11:12:53, Unlock event detected ----> Matching pattern
.....
.....
11:13:53, presence service not connected ----> next matching pattern 
.....
.....
```

I need to get 11:12:53 and 11:13:53 not 10:12:53

```
# Collect the list of hits
list_log = []
# opening the file
with open (file,'r', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
#for loop and find the matching pattern
    for l in lines:
        if re.findall(r"Unlock event detected", l):
            list_log.append(l)
        elif re.findall(r'presence service not connected',l):
            list_log.append(l)
    for ll in list_log:
        print(ll)
```

Comment: And after the second pattern is matched, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get into list_log the two lines you wanted you only need to place additional conditionals on when you log.

```
import re

list_log = []
# opening the file
with open (file,'r', errors='ignore') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    # find the matching patterns
    for l in lines:
        if not list_log and re.findall(r"Unlock event detected", l):
            list_log.append(l)
        elif list_log and re.findall(r'presence service not connected',l):
            list_log.append(l)
            break

    print(*list_log, sep = "\n")
```

**Output (using your data as file)**

```
11:12:53, Unlock event detected ----> Matching pattern
11:13:53, presence service not connected ----> next matching pattern
```